# I want my random to be less random

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, random

Let's say i have a list. I want to iterate over that list and add 2 random strings from it to an empty list. However, because this is a random choice, there is a possibility that the same string will be picked twice (As it is crucial not to pop or delete from that list the selected item). something like this:

```
import random

emptylist = []
somelist = ["a","b","c","d","e",]

for item in somelist:
    emptylist.append(random.choice(somelist))
    emptylist.append(random.choice(somelist))
```

How do i make sure that it won't pick, for example, "a" twice? 
I know it is possible in many ways but im looking for the most efficient one.

Comment: I'm sorry my code is bad.

import random

emptylist = []
somelist = ["a","b","c","d","e",]


emptylist.append(random.choice(somelist))
emptylist.append(random.choice(somelist))

Comment: Your code is not bad, just a wrong approach. Don't post code in a comment, if you want to update your question, just [edit] it. However, I've closed it as a duplicate, the answer on the other question also applies here: you want to use `random.sample()`, not `random.choice()`.